# How do you remove every second row in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I’ve read a file into a dataframe, and every second row is n/a. How do I remove the offending blank rows?

Comment: Df.dropna(in place=true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming there are many ways to do this. But I just use iloc

df = df.iloc[::2,:]

Try it and let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: you don't need the second `:`. Just `df.iloc[::2]`.